# Docker Compose Shiny Server (rocker) - can't access latest shiny package and functions

Tags: r, docker, shiny, docker-compose, shiny-server

I am trying to install the latest shiny package in my shiny docker container so I can leverage the `moduleServer` function now part of the shiny package. In the logs I check I can see that while the container gets set up without issue, for whatever reason when I run the current `rocker/shiny` repo, it installs an older shiny, specifically version 1.4.0.2 which doesn't have the function `moduleServer`. ***Does anyone know how to get the latest shiny package installed?***

I've tried:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/shiny/shiny_1.6.0.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
```

But then get errors about missing `bsib` and `cachem` and `htmlTools` as well, but they won't fully install. For example:

```
install.packages('bslib')
Warning message:
package ‘bslib’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)
```

I can try pulling the tar file but this seems to be the wrong way to go about it so curious if anyone has any tips.

**Dockerfile** is below:

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.0.0



RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools')" \ 
    R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown', 'shinydashboard', 'scales', 'DT', 'zoo', 'plotly', 'data.table','lubridate','Hmisc'))" && \
    cp -R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/examples/* /srv/shiny-server/ && \
    chown shiny:shiny /var/lib/shiny-server

EXPOSE 3838
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'

    services:
      rstudio:
        container_name: rstudio
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: rstudio/.
        volumes: 
          - /Users/mac/Documents/git_projects/docker-rstudio/scripts_example:/home/rstudio//example_scripts
        environment:
          - TZ=America/New_York
          - PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}
        ports:
          - 8888:8787
      shiny:
        container_name: shiny
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: shiny/.
        ports:
          - 8080:3838
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured a workaround on my end. Modified the Dockerfile as such:

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.0.0

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rmarkdown', 'shinydashboard', 'scales', 'DT', 'zoo', 'plotly', 'data.table','lubridate','Hmisc'))" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rappdirs_0.3.3.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rlang_0.4.12.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/fastmap_1.1.0.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/htmltools_0.5.2.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/sass_0.4.0.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/jquerylib_0.1.4.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/bslib_0.3.1.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/cachem_1.0.6.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rlang_0.4.12.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/fontawesome_0.2.2.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/shiny_1.7.1.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')" && \
    cp -R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/examples/* /srv/shiny-server/ && \
    chown shiny:shiny /var/lib/shiny-server

EXPOSE 3838

#COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
#RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

#CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```